# How to pass a function in the tuple argument in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to pass a function in the tuple argument? *players is a tuple.

this is one function inside a class (TicTacToe)

```
def play_game(self, *players):
        state = self.initial
        while True:
            for player in players:
                move = player(self, state)
                state = self.result(state, move)
                if self.terminal_test(state):
                    self.display(state)
                    return self.utility(state, self.to_move(self.initial))
```

How can I pass the below function in *players arguments?

```
def alpha_beta_player(game, state):
    return alpha_beta_search(state, game)
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
ttt = MyTicTacToe()
u = ttt.play_game(alpha_beta_player,alpha_beta_player)
print(u)
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?  Passing the functions looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks proper to me too:

`class MyTicTacToe:
    def play_game(self, *players):
        num = 2
        for player in players:
            val = player(num)
            print(val)
            if val == 7:
                return val


def add_five(num):
    return num + 5


def mul_by_three(num):
    return num * 3


ttt = MyTicTacToe()
u = ttt.play_game(add_five, mul_by_three)
print(u)`

Answer (score 1):

Enclose passed tuple in parentheses and unpack with *

```
ttt = MyTicTacToe()
u = ttt.play_game(*(alpha_beta_player,alpha_beta_player))
print(u)
```

Comment: what about the argument of alpha_beta_player function?

Comment: my method u = ttt.play_game(alpha_beta_player,alpha_beta_player) is also working

Comment: Edited please check, call with brackets